# Sitefinity create a page before application starts

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, content-management-system, sitefinity-8

I'm trying to create a default page for a control which is developed in Sitefinity cms system using the fluent api.

The page creation lies in the installer part of that particular control.
I have added the code in `installer.cs` so that page creation will happen only once after installation. But the system is not allowing to create the page. Due to authentication part before that(my guess). since the page needs to be owned by some username.

So i tried to pass some security info for authentication. Below is the code

```
UserLoggingReason result = SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser("Default", "username","password", true);
```

But the above line always throws null reference exception, i dont know what needs to be done in that.

Answer (score 1):

The code should not be in the installer.cs but rather in the module.cs file.
You will see that in the Install method there is a call to:

```
this.InstallBackendPages(initializer);
```

and there you can create your page like this:

```
Guid groupPageId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Guid pageId = Guid.NewGuid();

        initializer.Installer
            .CreateModuleGroupPage(groupPageId, "EmptyCustomModule1 group page")
                .PlaceUnder(SiteInitializer.SitefinityNodeId)
                .SetOrdinal(100)
                .LocalizeUsing<AvalonNotificationsResources>()
                .SetTitle("Avalon")
                .SetUrlName("avalon")
                .ShowInNavigation()
                .AddChildPage(pageId, "Test Page")
                    .SetOrdinal(1)
                    .LocalizeUsing<AvalonNotificationsResources>()
                    .SetTitle("Test Page")
                    .SetUrlName("test-page")
                    .AddUserControl("~/UserControls/TestWidget.ascx", "Content")
                    .AddControl(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal()
                     {
                         Text = "<h1 class=\"sfBreadCrumb\">Test Widget</h1>",
                         Mode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.LiteralMode.PassThrough
                     })
                    .ShowInNavigation()
                .Done()
            .Done();
```

This definitely works for me without supplying any user credentials because the Install method is called only when an Admin activates the module and clicks Install - this means it is already running under Admin privileges.

Comment: It should, but you would need to replace  .PlaceUnder(SiteInitializer.SitefinityNodeId) with an Id of a front-end page of your choise.

Comment: Where the file `module.cs` will be ? any documentation from sitefinity?

Comment: Well, if you'd used Sitefinity Thunder to create your custom module then it would have created a file called YourModuleNameInstaller.cs and YourModuleNameModule.cs (plus a lot more files and folders).